# What is ファンクラブ here?

Tags: meaning

Here's how it was used (taken from a JLPT listening question):

A: わたし、ジャンプジャンプのコンサートに行きたい。

B: もうチケットないよ、きっと。ファンクラブに電話して聞いてみる?

So, is this not literally a fan club?

Is this implying that you get tickets from a fan club? If they're fans, why would they sell tickets? Their own tickets? How does concert ticket selling work? (I am cultural-illiterate here I guess.)

Sorry if I'm overthinking it. よろしくおねがいします

Comment: Official fan clubs are pretty common. It's not that different from joining a discount club for a store, but it's for a musician or sports team instead.

Comment: In Japan, fan clubs often do sell tickets and things like this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will try not to overgeneralize things here, but there are at least two types of 「ファンクラブ」 for Japanese musicians, athletes, etc.

**Type 1: Official fan clubs (公設{こうせつ}/公式{こうしき}ファンクラブ)**

These are often run by the management companies responsible for promoting their "celebs".  These usually charge you fees to join and to maintain your membership on a yearly basis.

**Type 2: Unofficial, "privately-run" fan clubs (私設{しせつ}ファンクラブ)**

These are mostly run by the fans for a more purely non-business basis.

It is the Type 1 fan clubs that manage event tickets.  (Type 2 simply does not possess that kind of power.)  Their members, naturally, are often given priority in getting the tickets.

This is why what B states makes perfect sense in Japanese culture.  The official fan club has the most up-to-date information on the ticket sales.